# HP EliteDesk 800 G2 SFF - what is the strongest graphic card I can put in?

Tags: graphics-cards

My niece is working her school duties on this computer - HP EliteDesk 800 G2 SFF and now requires better graphics card. What is the strongest card I can put in?
All advice is appreciated.
[image]
Inside:
[image]
Edit:

- I added some images I could find online, I don't have physical access to the machine ATM
- power supply is 280W

Comment: Can you edit your question with a picture of the inside, the power supply wattage and a picture of the back?

Answer (score 1):

The Zotac Gaming GeForce GTX 1650 Low Profile is one of the few graphics cards that fit your pc, and seeing your pictures, you don't have a GPU power connector, just like this one.

I don't know if it's the fastest GPU that fits, but it's good enough for 1080p gaming. When overclocked, it is about the same speed as my RX 570, but that one doesn't fit in your case and requires too much power.